# can i load a controller from a plugin in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible in codeigniter to call/load a controller/view/model from a plugin/library? if possible then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load view/model by calling refference to main CI object:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('sm_model');
$CI->sm_model->do_smth();
$CI->load->view('sm_view');
```

To call controller that way (and to be able to call one controller from another one) you'll need to install [hmvc module](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)